# cpp double pointer vs 2 dimensional array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
    int *c = *a;
    int **b = &c;
    std::cout << **(a+1);  // outputs 3
    std::cout << **(b+1);  // segmentation fault
}
```

Why does one cout results in segmentation fault and other doesn't? Shouldn't they be referring to the same value?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::array` and/or `std::vector`? C-style arrays seem "quaint" these days..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
cout << **(b+1);
```

the expression `b+1` points outside the array (that is more precisely outside the object c). You should write

```
cout << *( *b + 2 );
```

The dereferenced pointer `b` points to the pointer to the first element of the two-dimensional array. When adding to it the number of elements in the array of the type int[2] you will get the pointer to the first element of the second "row" of the two-dimensional array. Now you need again to dereference it to output the pointed value.

Comment: makes sense, how does the compiler keep track of this information for the array pointer? since it doesn't throw segmentation fault

Comment: @RohithYeravothula I'm sorry. I have not understood the question.

Answer (score 4):

Lets start with

```
int *c;
```

Actually what comes before is not that relevant, because `c` is just a pointer and then here

```
int **b = &c;
```

you store the address of `c` in `b`. The address of `c` has nothing to do with what value is stored in `c`. `c` is just a pointer, taking its adress doesn't let you magically access a 2d array.

```
cout << **(b+1); // segmentation fault
```

Already `b+1` is undefined behaviour. Dereferencing that pointer cannot give you something meaningful.

PS: tbh I cannot tell you how to use the double pointers correctly here. Once I started to learn c++ I unlearned anything I knew about working with arrays via pointers. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` and save yourself some headaces.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code to highlight what is happening, as below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
  int *c[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
  int **b = c;

  std::cout << **(a  ) << ','; // outputs 1
  std::cout << **(b  ) << ";\n"; // outputs 1
  std::cout << **(a+1) << ','; // outputs 3
  std::cout << **(b+1) << ";\n"; // outputs 3
}
```

LINK: https://ideone.com/ixj3NV

**UPDATED LINK**: https://ideone.com/g7jjVN
(Clarified the original source to extend the program)